# Inner Join Max Value in table MYSQL (PhpMyadmin)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to write a MySQL query  using phpmyadmin, 
I need to take the Maximun 'Site' In 'Value1'  but,  with the condition of having 'Value2'>10 OR 'Value3' > 10.

In this image i show the Expected Result.

[image: Expected Result of Query. CLICK]
Thanks.

I Try this, but it does not work

*SELECT Value1,Value2,Value3,Value FROM mytable b1*

WHERE Value2= ( SELECT MAX( b2.Value2) FROM mytable b2 WHERE b1.`Value1`=b2.`Value1`)

Please, i nedd a general scheme to solve this problem.

Comment: Where is your query attempt?

Comment: Hint: look into post aggregation filtering

Comment: What would happen if there's multiple values in Value1 which are equal to the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT t1.Site, t1.Value1, t1.Value2, t1.Value3 
FROM Table t1
WHERE Value1=(
      SELECT MAX(t2.Value1) 
      FROM Table t2 
      WHERE t2.Site = t1.Site
) AND t1.Value2 > 10 AND t1.Value3 > 10;
```

If you have mutliple values in value1 which are equal to the maximum, you'd get them all as long as the value2 and value3 conditions are maintained.

If you don't want that then GROUP BY Site at the end or select DISTINCT Site.

Comment: thanks , it works, but my original table has 70K records , and the query takes up to 5 minutes

Comment: @geraqf if there's none, add an index to Value1 and Site. If that doesn't help then you may consider adding a unique primary key column on table and then instead of a nested select you can do a join on the key which corresponds to the max value.